# lot of empty sql statements in mysql + hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I have simple spring + hibernate + mysql project. Turning on the query logs on the mysql server i see lots and lots of frequent "SET autocommit=0;commit;SET autocommit=0"   statements without executing anything on my application.

Which process/why of my application is executing these frequent queries? I've listed bellow the connection pool configuration.

Please note that:

- usual sql queries (from my application) are working and logged here
- these logs are very frequent like 1-4 per seconds.
- if i undeploy my application all these "SET autocommit=0;commit;SET
  autocommit=0" logs will stop

  > 131001 10:41:31    2046 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2046 Query commit
  >              2046 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2046 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2046 Query commit
  >              2046 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2046 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2046 Query commit
  >              2046 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2061 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2061 Query commit
  >              2061 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2061 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2061 Query commit
  >              2061 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2061 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2061 Query commit
  >              2061 Query SET autocommit=1
  >       131001 10:41:34    2051 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2051 Query commit
  >              2051 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2051 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2051 Query commit
  >              2051 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2051 Query SET autocommit=0
  >              2051 Query commit
  >              2051 Query SET autocommit=1
  >              2047 Query SET autocommit=0

  ```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
       <property name="jdbcUrl" value="" />
       <property name="username" value="..."/>
       <property name="password" value="..."/>
       <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60"/>
       <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240"/>      
       <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
       <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="5"/>
       <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
       <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>                              
       <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="300"/>
       <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
       <property name="connectionTestStatement" value="/* ping *\/ SELECT 8"/>

   </bean>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those logs are outputted when your application starts a transaction. Try to dump stack traces with `jstack` and see what threads and when are opening the transactions.

Some references:

[innodb and autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/innodb-and-autocommit.html)
[jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html)